# How to monitor several sites for updates from one central site?

Tags: 7, updating

I have several Drupal sites and wish to have one site list all of their "status" and available updates. So to start with I am trying to find how to get the available updates.

The central site has access to the databases of all of the others so I am hoping to pull info direct from there but I have no clue where to look.

Is there a table with such information that is auto updated on cron etc?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Drupal Remote Dashboard](https://www.drupal.org/project/drd) module for this

> This module is for system administrators. It's a tool to monitor and manage any number of Drupal installations at once and it's built to be extensible by other modules. Since version 2.X this module also comes with the highest level of security where as all communication between the dashboard and each of the cores is AES encrypted, hence the dependency (see below). Optionally the monitoring data will be made visible in nice graphs if the Google Chart API is available.

Answer (score 1):

#### Contributed modules for Site Monitoring

Some of the child pages about [Monitoring a site](https://www.drupal.org/node/627162) (which also has a childpage about [Drupal Remote Dashboard](https://www.drupal.org/node/1450592), mentioned in another answer already) describe some other relevant topics, such as:

- [Viewing log messages](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/dblog), using the (Drupal core) *Database logging* module.
- [Information about the Drupal installation and system environment](https://www.drupal.org/node/82694), using the [System Information](https://www.drupal.org/project/systeminfo) module.
- [Custom lists of modules and themes](https://www.drupal.org/node/1203810), using the [Views System](http://drupal.org/project/views_system) module.
- [Custom lists of watchdog entries](https://www.drupal.org/node/1225540), using the [Views Watchdog](http://drupal.org/project/views_watchdog) module.

The table(s) these module operate on, are probably the table(s) you are looking for.

#### Custom reporting and charting

The contributed modules mentioned before typically offer canned reports / charts / queries. On top of that, you probably also want to consider all sorts of "Custom Report and/or Charts". For inspiration about what is possible in that area, consider looking at these questions / answers:

- [Find out who updated Drupal modules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/162134/find-out-who-updated-drupal-modules/162140?s=1|0.3568#162140).
- [How to query the Database logs and create summary reports and/or charts of them?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/144883/is-there-a-module-for-querying-and-creating-summary-reports-of-the-database-logs/150148#150148)
- [How to report about how many users have registered in a given timeframe?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/133816/users-report-module/150184#150184)

Comment: Not sure if this is what is asked in the question.